# Display a list of images in shiny using renderImage/renderUI where the images 5 at a time with a next button for the next 5?

Tags: r, image, shiny, reactive, flexdashboard

I have a reactive list of image paths that I'm able to display in a shiny flexdashboard. However, sometimes the list of images is quite long, causing the images to take a while to load. Does shiny have a relevant function or a way to load them by 5 at a time, where a user can press a "next"-type button to see the next 5?

Comment: `DT::dataTableOutput` and `DT::renderDataTable` has paging included

Comment: Try the **slickR** package. This is a wrapper of **slick js**: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: wow thank you! Will try out both of these options